# How to compensate and give back what I've stolen?

Tags: practical-islam, theft

I am 14 and 1 or 2 years ago I have stolen a book from my friend without her knowledge. She had inquired once about it, and she is my very close friend. I have repented to Allah (S.W.T) to forgive my sins.

However, one of the pages of the book got torn and has been misplaced. I intend to call my friend, say sorry and return the book, however, it has been torn.

**Question:**

What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

> **قَالَ رَسُولُ اللَّهِ ص رُفِعَ الْقَلَمُ عَنْ ثَلَاثَةٍ عَنِ النَّائِمِ حَتَّى يَسْتَيْقِظَ وَ عَنِ الْمَجْنُونِ حَتَّى يُفِيقَ وَ
>   عَنِ الطِّفْلِ حَتَّى يَحْتَلِمَ**

The Prophet (peace be upon him) said: The pen of responsibility has been lifted from three groups: from sleepers until they wake up, from the insane until they are recovered and from children until they reach puberty.

As long as you have not reached the age at which you become **duty bound**(*Bulugh*)[1](http://islamquest.net/en/archive/question/fa6945), you are not obliged to make up for what you have done wrong.

However, rights related to people have to be compensated. The point is that as long as you have not reached the age of Bulugh, your parents are to be held accountable. but if you have become duty bound you are the responsible of making up for the damages you did to others' properties.

Therefore, you have to gain the satisfaction of the person from whom you have stolen a book by giving back the book if possible or another edition of the book if possible or the price of the book as the last resort.

**[1**] For further information about the age of *Bulugh* please visit **[this link](http://islamquest.net/en/archive/question/fa6945)**

Comment: I thought by <strike>14</strike> getting matured, youth become big people in Islam.

Answer (score 0):

Young man, when you took this book I'm sure Allah was not in you your mind or your conscience, otherwise you would not have took it.
Always remember Allah is oft-forgiving, most merciful.
So my advice is to be brave and return the book, then, when you pray, ask for your forgiveness.
Believe me you are young there are people on this earth a lot older than you who commit a lot of bad sins.
It's good that you understand your fault, ask for forgiveness and don't let this matter strain you.

Answer (score 0):

When I borrow an item from someone and damage it, I buy a new item exactly like the damaged item and give the new item to them. I then keep the old, damaged item for myself. Everybody is happy that way.